# jQuery key event with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, keydown

I have a jquery key event listener which looks for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> event. My problem is commented below.

```
jQuery(window).on('keydown', function(e){

    if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == '67')
    {
        // console.log('pressed'); This works
        // $scope.closeShareBar(); This works
        $scope.showNotif('The URL has been copied to your clipboard', null, true); // This DOES NOT work
    }

});

$scope.showNotif('The URL has been copied to your clipboard', null, true); // This works
```

Why is it not working?
`$scope.showNotif()` is a function I have written to show notifications.

**edit**
I hope i have made it clear that `$scope.closeShareBar();` works without `$apply()`. Why does only this work then? Isn't this angular too?

**edit 2**

```
$scope.showNotif = function(text, status, closeEnabled, quick){
    $scope.notif_text = text;
    $scope.notif = status || 'show';
    if (closeEnabled == true)
    {
        $timeout.cancel($scope.timer);
        $scope.timer = $timeout(function(){
            $scope.notif = '';
        }, 3000);
    }
    if (quick == true)
    {
        $scope.notif = '';
    }
}
```

```
$scope.closeShareBar = function(){

    // $scope.shareLink = 'http://localhost:3000/single-signal/'+id;
    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.signal_wrapper .signal_data')).removeClass('share_overlay');
    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.signal_wrapper .sb_status .share')).removeClass('hide');
    angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.signal_wrapper .sb_status .close')).addClass('hide');

}
```

Comment: Is the failing line reached if you set a debug breakpoint?

Comment: You may have to do $scope.$apply() if you are looking for some scope binding updates that happens inside showNotif.

Comment: You do need scope.apply only when you update scope property that are bound to the view. Without seeing what `showNotif` does it is hard to help.

Comment: added `$scope.showNotif`

Comment: As i commented earlier you have properties that are bound to the view which gets updated in the function, so you need scope.apply inside the jquery event handler. and `closeShareBar` works because you are directly manipulating DOM

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you do something outside of angular, you need to notify it that you've done a change. So right after your $scope.showNotif you'll need to do a $scope.$apply();

```
$scope.showNotif(...);
$scope.$apply();
```